# Mouse jumps around in games when pressing middle mouse button

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, gaming, steam

The problem I experience is happening when pressing the middle mouse button (or equivalently "mouse wheel button") in a game where you can aim with the cursor.

I am using a "Mad Catz R.A.T 3"-mouse but this may not be the problem because I experienced the same problem with a mouse from Microsoft.

The problem is that the cursor jumps to some "random" (x,y)-coordinate after pressing the middle mouse button. For me this is happening for the games CS:GO and Darksiders II.

Note that this problem is neither happening at my desktop nor in many other games (but I did not test other similar games though). My middle mouse button has the standard configuration, i.e. it is configured to trigger "Autoscroll", if available (usually in desktop only) and by pressing it on a tab in a browser, it will close the tab.

The following YouTube clip describes my problem pretty well (except that the video owner experiences it with the "right mouse button"):
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHd8yxCZqrM

Now this could also be Steam related (because both games are running through Steam) but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The usual steps to finding the culprit for an issue like this are:

- Try different USB ports
- Uninstall mouse drivers (if you're running custom mouse drivers)
- Try in safe mode
- Try the applications in windowed mode instead of full screen, or vice versa.
- Try the mouse(s) on a different PC in the same apps if possible
- Disable any/all overlay or hooked programs (steam overlay, voice chat, wall hacks, etc)

Comment: "Can't comment because I haven't got 50 rep." - Your inability to submit comments on purpose.  Please earn the required reputation before you comment on questions or answers.  You can do that by asking your own questions or answering a question.  Your inability to post comments currently is on purpose, getting around the restrictions, will only result in this answer being removed by the community.  If you have enough answers deleted by the community, your ability to answer questions, will be taken away automatically by the system.  Once this happens it cannot be reversed.

Comment: You had some good information in your post. Since you can't post comments yet, you just have to get creative with the answer (e.g. if you have x, then do y, otherwise z).